Can not customize PrimeVue theme with vue.js app when using TypeScript
I would like to customize PrimeVue theme in my vue.js app.  So I need to have import like this in my main.ts file: import { definePreset } from '@primevue/themes'.  It works fine when not using typeScript in my app but when I install TypeScript an error occures: "Module '"@primevue/themes"' has no exported member 'definePreset'." Idk how to solve it...
Simple samples:

App base with TypeScript installed (does not work): https://github.com/Petr-Brozek/primevue-playground
App base without TypeScript (works fine): https://github.com/Petr-Brozek/primevue-playground-nots


Please, provide a way to reproduce. The package seems to have correct types and is expected to work

@Estus Flask sure, I've attached two apps, one that works and one that doesn't.  Thanks for any help!

You're using old TS version. This results in incompatible ts files that fail to be parsed to be ignored.

The question needs to contain all relevant code in addition to the link. Copilot has no human brains, it's unknown where the info comes from but it has no way to confirm this in practice. It can be seen that the package reexports @primeuix/styled. Node/TS ecosystem has no habit to specify TS version in a project, but you can see at least this is very possible because new TS version was used to develop it, https://github.com/primefaces/primeuix/blob/main/package.json#L42 This is a common TS problem, and TS version is the first to blame for the reason I mentioned, d.ts is ignored with no error

As advised by Estus Flask, when I updated Typescript (to v. 5.6.3) the problem is solved.
